# how to get decimal values as a new interger and traverse that integer from left to right?

Tags: java

I have a business case where I need to get the decimal values as a new integer and 
then traverse it from left to right to evaluate.

```
Eg: I have a integer value int val=1345679;
    square root of val is double sqrt_val=1160.03405122; //sqrt(1345679), decimal values are limit to 8 digits
    Now I need decimal value(03405122) to store it into integer variable

    int decimalValue=03405122;

    With this decimal value I want to verify with some number which is given by business. 
    Let's take some number as 45.

    now I have to verify decimalValue until it meets the below condition
         03405122<=45 if yes just take the decimal value 
                      if no then remove the 1st digit from left side until condition satisfiet
          3405122<=45
           405122<=45
            05122<=45
             5122<=45
              122<=45
               22<=45.
       So, 22 is the number I have to take for further implementation.
```

This is the code which I have written, and give me some suggestions that If I can write in a better way.

// Extracting Decimal value

```
    public int extractDecimal(int computeRandomNumber) 
   {
    int _computeRandom = computeRandomNumber;
    double sqrt = Math.sqrt(_computeRandom);
    BigDecimal df;
    df = round(sqrt, 8);
    // System.out.println(df);
    String sqrt_round = String.valueOf(df);
    // System.out.println(sqrt_round);
    int index = sqrt_round.lastIndexOf('.') + 1;
    String sqrt_round_deci = sqrt_round.substring(index);
    // System.out.println(sqrt_round_deci);
    return Integer.parseInt(sqrt_round_deci);
    }
```

//Comparing with the some number to find the random number

```
public int findRandomNumber(int value, int totalRange) {
    int _val;
    System.out.println("calling rec::: val:" + value);

    if (value <= totalRange) {
        System.out.println("Success... returing on final value:" + value);
        return value;
    }
    String new_str = String.valueOf(value);
    String final_str = new_str.substring(1);
    // System.out.println("str:"+final_str);
    int val = Integer.parseInt(final_str);
    // System.out.println("val:"+val);
    _val = findRandomNumber(val, totalRange);       
    return _val;
    // System.out.println("Returning flag:"+flag);
}
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You can convert the number into a String, and then do numeric compare between this String and your number with an ever diminishing String, until your '<=' condition is met.

Comment: Hi, this forum is strictly dedicated to programming. You may have question about algorithms, but you need at least to specify a language in which you implement your algorithm. Maybe you posted your question on the wrong forum, or you need to specify in which langage you intend to implement your algo.

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with Spring or Java-EE.  This is a simple Java programming task.

Comment: Sorry guys, It's not like I am not done any homework and asking to do my homework. My intention was just to see the different ideas and wanted to choose best one. I am updating the post with my code. Please help me if I can write in a better way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As you provided a pseudo-code only question, I will be generous and provide a pseudo-code only answer:

*1)* Get the `String` value of `sqrt_val`

*2)* Use the [`substring()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)) method to get only the places<sup>1</sup> after the `.`

*3)* Loop through the length<sup>2</sup> of said `substring`

*4)* Check on each iteration if the `valueOf` your `String` is less than your target

*5a)* If so, there's your result

*5b)* If not, get the `substring` starting from position 1

<sup>1</sup> <sub>If this begins with a 0, your results may vary so I'll leave this for you to work out</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>If you use this way, be careful if your loop goes via `String.length` as you use a `substring` in the `else`</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I am in no way convinced that this is the best solution but here's an alternative solution which doesn't use Strings.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Value to be less than
        BigDecimal lessThan = new BigDecimal(80);
        int test = 333444;
        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal( Math.sqrt(test) );
        System.out.println(bd);
        while( bd.scale() > 0 ) {
            // get the fractional value and make it a whole number
            BigDecimal fractionOnly = bd.divideAndRemainder(BigDecimal.ONE)[1];
            fractionOnly = fractionOnly.movePointRight(fractionOnly.scale());

            // do the check
            System.out.println( fractionOnly + " < " + lessThan );
            if ( fractionOnly.compareTo( lessThan ) < 0 ) {
                System.out.println( "Yes" );
                break;
            }

            // method kinda says it
            bd = bd.movePointRight(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very neat. You might want to add the class and import statement needed to get this to compile, making it complete.

Comment: I didn't want to make it too easy for them :) Good point though, I'll add in.